# Updating User defined field in POOrder while creating Drop ship PO

Tags: acumatica

I have to override function to create drop ship PO and update custom field in PO Table based on sales price margin goes below certain percentage. I have gone through the source code for POCreate.
The PO is created through static function

```
public static PXRedirectRequiredException CreatePOOrders(List<POFixedDemand> list, DateTime? PurchDate, bool extSort)
```

How to override and add my logic to creating drop-ship PO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to attach event handlers on what you need. This is not a simple case but here's an example I wrote a couple months ago. This code is changing the POLine description to add "Test" at the end. You could use it populate your custom fields too.

```
public class POCreateExt : PXGraphExtension<POCreate>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<POOrderEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowUpdating.AddHandler<POLine>((sender, e) =>
            {
                POLine line = e.NewRow as POLine;
                POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3 soLine = PXResult<POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3>.Current;
                line.TranDesc = soLine.TranDesc + " TEST ";
            });
        });
    }
}
```