# Need help carrying Sales Order user fields to Create Purchase order screen

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization where I have added three user fields to the Sales Order (SO301000) screen transactions grid.  I would like to set fields on the 'Create Purchase Order' screen (PO505000).  I had used the POFixedDemand's 'RowSelected' event, which works fine - but that causes a problem when anyone tries to modify anything in a row - which re-triggers that event - not a desired outcome.

I've tried the 'RowInserting' and 'RowInserted' events - but they're never triggered.  I'm assuming at this point that I'll have to intercept some code in the 'POCreate' BLC that creates the POFixedDemand records in the Create Purchase Order screen - but I don't really know where to start.  Would I put it somewhere in the EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemands method?

Here's the code I created which works for the RowSelected event, but is no good for when a row is modified by a user.  Any help is appreciated.   Thank you.

```
    protected virtual void POFixedDemand_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pofd = (POFixedDemand)e.Row;
        if (pofd == null) return;

        var filter = Base.Filter.Current;
        var ordernbr = filter.OrderNbr;
        var ordertype = filter.OrderType;

        var solinesplit = (SOLineSplit)PXSelect<SOLineSplit, Where<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.planID>>>>.Select(Base, pofd.PlanID);
        if (solinesplit != null)
        {
            var soline = (SOLine)PXSelect<SOLine,
                                 Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>,
                                 And<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>,
                                 And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>>.Select(Base, solinesplit.OrderNbr, solinesplit.OrderType, solinesplit.LineNbr);

            if (soline != null)
            {
                var solineext = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soline);
                pofd.VendorID = solineext.UsrVendor;
                pofd.EffPrice = solineext.UsrVendorUnitCost;
                pofd.ExtCost = solineext.UsrVendorExtendedCost;

                //Now set the Vendor location...
                var location = (Location)PXSelect<Location,
                                         Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, pofd.VendorID);

                if (location != null)
                {
                    pofd.LocationID = location.LocationID;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came up with after some investigation is to override the 'EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemands' method to set the values.  Code is as follows:

```
    public delegate IEnumerable EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemandsDelegate(PXResultset<POFixedDemand> fixedDemands);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemands(PXResultset<POFixedDemand> fixedDemands, EnumerateAndPrepareFixedDemandsDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        foreach (PXResult<POFixedDemand> rec in fixedDemands)
        {
            POFixedDemand demand = rec;

            var solinesplit = (SOLineSplit)PXSelect<SOLineSplit, Where<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<Required<SOLineSplit.planID>>>>.Select(Base, demand.PlanID);
            if (solinesplit != null)
            {
                var soline = (SOLine)PXSelect<SOLine,
                             Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>,
                             And<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>,
                             And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>>.Select(Base, solinesplit.OrderNbr, solinesplit.OrderType, solinesplit.LineNbr);
                if (soline != null)
                {
                    var solineext = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soline);
                    demand.VendorID = solineext.UsrVendor;
                    demand.EffPrice = solineext.UsrVendorUnitCost;
                    demand.ExtCost = solineext.UsrVendorExtendedCost;

                    //Now set the Vendor location...
                    var location = (Location)PXSelect<Location,
                                             Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, solineext.UsrVendor);

                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        demand.VendorLocationID = location.LocationID;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return baseMethod(fixedDemands);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming at this point that I'll have to intercept some code in
>   the 'POCreate' BLC

Yes you need to do something along those lines.
There's a similar answer here for initializing the POLine instead of POFixedDemand:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255340/7376238

With some minor adjustments, the general pattern would be:

```
public class POCreateExt : PXGraphExtension<POCreate>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<POOrderEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<POFixedDemand>((sender, e) =>
            {
                // Initialize fields when row is inserted
                POFixedDemand demand = e.Row as POFixedDemand;
                demand.DACField = [initialization value];
            });

            graph.RowUpdating.AddHandler<POFixedDemand>((sender, e) =>
            {
                // Sometimes fields are updated so you need to 
                // hook RowUpdating too and re-initialize
                POFixedDemand demand = e.NewRow as POFixedDemand;
                demand.DACField = [initialization value];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I went ahead and dug around the source code and I may have solved the problem (see below).  Thanks for your help.